# list of all available CSS colors (for the background)

Tags: css, colors

I am writing some tiny javascript where in essence the content of a input text value is used to set the backgroundColor of a div

**`div.style.backgroundColor = inputText.value;`**

The page might look like this:

Color: [black]

**DIV**

Because people might mispell the color I want to change it to a combobox.

The question is how do I know the list of all available colors ?
e.g. orange, cyan,blue,aqua  are standard
but blueaqua is not

Comment: This [**link**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp) might help you :) (Wondering whether to/not to post this as an answer :P)

Comment: Why not make it even easier for your users and use [some sort of color picker](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/)?

Comment: @Harry that link is not official.

Comment: @DavidThomas that link is not official... how do I know if it's going to work on Chrome or opera or god knows

Comment: @DavidThomas - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the complete list at w3c

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/